# IBM eDiscovery Manager (CSN to eml) email conversion causes com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNParseException: could not locate data

Tags: java

When converting the *.csn(CommonStore Native) file to *.eml file using the edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar csn parse exception is thrown.

Below is the code,

1. "Filestream" is a file inputstream.
2. "id" is just a filename.
3. templocation is a location where the EML file will be stored after conversion

```
    EmailConverterService emailConv = new EmailConverterService();
    EmailItem emailItem = emailConv.convertStreamToEmailItem(fileStream, id, tempLocation);
```

Below is the error code

```
com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNParseException: could not locate data
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNHandler.parse(CSNHandler.java:497) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNHandler.parse(CSNHandler.java:292) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.EmailConverterService.parseEmailContent(EmailConverterService.java:964) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.EmailConverterService.convertStreamToEmailItem(EmailConverterService.java:336) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.EmailConverterService.convertStreamToEmailItem(EmailConverterService.java:214) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.exterro.edrm.connector.filenet.converter.EmlFileCreator.processCSNFile(EmlFileCreator.java:92) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.connector.filenet.helper.FileNetContentHelper.convertCSNFile(FileNetContentHelper.java:454) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.connector.filenet.helper.FileNetContentHelper.getInputStream(FileNetContentHelper.java:171) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.connector.filenet.FileNetConnectorHelper.getContent(FileNetConnectorHelper.java:328) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.connector.filenet.FileNetConnector.getContent(FileNetConnector.java:94) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.services.filenet.FileNetCollectorService.processSingleItem(FileNetCollectorService.java:1493) [file-net-collector-internal.5.19.jar:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.services.filenet.FileNetCollectorService.search(FileNetCollectorService.java:1375) [file-net-collector-internal.5.19.jar:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.services.filenet.FileNetCollectorService.start(FileNetCollectorService.java:390) [file-net-collector-internal.5.19.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.events.handler.MasterEventHandler.processEventRequest(MasterEventHandler.java:101) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.events.handler.MasterEventHandler.start(MasterEventHandler.java:58) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.events.handler.StartEventHandler.performEventAction(StartEventHandler.java:20) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.events.handler.manager.ListernerManager.performEventAction(ListernerManager.java:114) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.services.custom.connector.framework.ExterroCollectorCrawlHandler.start(ExterroCollectorCrawlHandler.java:229) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.services.custom.connector.framework.ExterroCollectorCrawler.startCrawl(ExterroCollectorCrawler.java:73) [classes/:?]
    at com.exterro.edrm.collector.core.service.CollectorService.run(CollectorService.java:105) [classes/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: could not locate data
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUData.getStream(ICUData.java:143) ~[icu4j-62.1.jar:62.1]
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUBinary.getData(ICUBinary.java:495) ~[icu4j-62.1.jar:62.1]
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUBinary.getRequiredData(ICUBinary.java:449) ~[icu4j-62.1.jar:62.1]
    at com.ibm.icu.charset.UConverterAlias.haveAliasData(UConverterAlias.java:131) ~[icu4j-charset-68.2.jar:68.2]
    at com.ibm.icu.charset.UConverterAlias.getCanonicalName(UConverterAlias.java:525) ~[icu4j-charset-68.2.jar:68.2]
    at com.ibm.icu.charset.CharsetProviderICU.getICUCanonicalName(CharsetProviderICU.java:126) ~[icu4j-charset-68.2.jar:68.2]
    at com.ibm.icu.charset.CharsetProviderICU.charsetForName(CharsetProviderICU.java:62) ~[icu4j-charset-68.2.jar:68.2]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$2.run(Charset.java:412) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$2.run(Charset.java:407) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookupViaProviders(Charset.java:406) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup2(Charset.java:477) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Charset.java:464) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.isSupported(Charset.java:505) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.StringCoding.lookupCharset(StringCoding.java:99) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:185) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:426) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:491) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNInputStream.readLMBCSEncodedString(CSNInputStream.java:717) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNInputStream.getString(CSNInputStream.java:684) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNReader.processText(CSNReader.java:459) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNReader.getNoteItemData(CSNReader.java:1311) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNReader.getItemValue(CSNReader.java:1526) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    at com.ibm.icm.edc.emailconv.domino.csn.CSNHandler.parse(CSNHandler.java:331) ~[edcemailconv-2.2.2.jar:${manifest.file.Implementation.Version} 11/19/2013 at 02:36 PM PT ]
    ... 24 more
```

I have even used Jdgui to go through the icu4j.jar

The error was in CSNHandler.class when the reader gets the value for "from"

> emailItem.setFormType(reader.getItemValue("form"));

in the below code.

```
if (EDCLogger.isLoggable(Level.FINEST))
      EDCLogger.log(Level.FINEST, "CSNHandler", "parse(InputStream)", "Entering."); 
    DominoEmailItem emailItem = new DominoEmailItem();
    
    try {
      CSNReader reader = new CSNReader(emailItem.getProcessingErrorProtocol(), stream, this.binDir, this.relativeDir, doCorrection);

      
      try {
        reader.readItems();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        if (e instanceof CSNReadItemException)
        {


          
          throw new CSNParseException("", 3002);
        }
        emailItem.getProcessingErrorProtocol().registerProcessingError(ProcessingDeviation.CSN_IO_READ_ERROR, e);
      } 
      
      emailItem.setFormType(reader.getItemValue("form"));
      emailItem.setUnid(reader.getUniversalNoteId());
      emailItem.setHasOLEAttachments(reader.hasEmbeddedObjects());
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with icu4j dependencies charset. I was using icu4j.version- 62.1 when I used the latest version icu4j.version-68.2 the .csn to .eml conversion was fine.